# Best way to display real-time data from an SSH accesible file on webpage

Tags: php, python, wordpress, ssh, html

I have a temperature logger that measures the records temperature values at specified time intervals. Currently I push these to a google spreadsheet but would like to display the values automatically on a web-page.

I have no experience with anything to do with web-pages, except setting up a few Wordpress sites but am reasonably comfortable with C++, Python, Matlab and Java.

A complicating factor is that the machine is in a VPN, so that access it via SSH I need to join the VPN.

I suspect the best way is to have a Python script that periodically send a up-to-date file to the web-server via ftp and then some script on the server that plots this.

My initial though was to use Python via something like CGI to read the data and create a plot on the server. However, I have no idea what the best approach on the server side would be. Is it worth to learn some PHP? Or should I write a Java Applet? Or CGI is the way to go?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html) implementation:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

function packet_handler($str)
{
    echo $str;
    @flush();
    @ob_flush();
}

$ssh->exec('ping 127.0.0.1', 'packet_handler');
?>
```

Comment: this worked but I have found it to difficult to set up a vpn connection, so I think I will push the data to the server rather than getting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a program monitor the file, either locally or via SSH.  Have that program push updates into your web backend, via HTTP API or such.